# ¿Cómo hacer un registro de usuarios incluyendo más campos utilizando forms.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

estoy empezando con Django y me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de registrar a los nuevos usuarios en el modelo por defecto pero añadiendo más campos como género, fecha de nacimiento, etc... Por lo que he leído, tendría que crear un modelo de perfil en models.py, parecido a esto:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Perfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
       id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name=u"ID")
       email=models.EmailField(max_length=50,verbose_name=u"Email")
       CHOICES = [('Mujer','Mujer'),('Hombre','Hombre'), ('PN', 'Prefiero no contestar')]
       genero = models.CharField(choices = CHOICES, max_length = 15, verbose_name=u"Género")
       fech_nac=models.DateField(verbose_name=u"Fecha Nac.")
       foto=models.FileField(upload_to='video', max_length=500, verbose_name=u"Foto")
       def __unicode__(self):
             return self.user.username
```

El problema es que no sé como hacer un formulario para incluir a los Users y el perfil. Y, después en views.py como guardar los datos en sus respectivas tablas.

Muchas gracias y espero haber podido expresarme bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en mi conocimiento te podría decir que no es necesario que crees una clase extra para tener mas atributos. Tu puedes colocar esos atributos dentro de la clase Usuario que hereda de la clase AbstractUser, es decir:

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
   CHOICES = [('Mujer','Mujer'),('Hombre','Hombre'), ('PN', 'Prefiero no contestar')]

   genero = models.CharField(choices = CHOICES, max_length = 15, 
   verbose_name=u"Género")
   fecha_nacimiento=models.DateField(verbose_name=u"Fecha Nac.")
   foto=models.FileField(upload_to='video', max_length=500, verbose_name=u"Foto")
```

Los campos de id e email no tendría sentido ponerlos ya que la misma clase por defecto los tiene y user pues claramente no iría ya que estamos hablando de la misma clase.

Para crear el formulario en forms.py creas tu clase de esta forma (Asumo que quieres crear un usuario):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UsuarioModelForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta:
    model = Usuario
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'genero', 'fecha_nacimiento','foto')
```

Con esto ya podras tener tu formulario con los nuevos campos lo siguiente es que lo llames a tu views.py y lo pongas en un template

Nota: no te olvides de colocarle al  para que puedas guardar archivos
Nota 2: En tus modelos como consejo coloca los nombres de la forma mas explicita por ejemplo: fech_nac por fecha_de_nacimiento

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba días intentando encontrar algo, hasta que tú has me has resuelto la duda :)

Comment: @123T recuerda aceptar la respuesta si ha resuelto tu problema o duda, marcando el visto en la parte izquierda de la respuesta.